# Want to grab text from anywhere on my phone screen

Tags: java, android

I want to code this in java for Android use. The desired outcome is that I could grab a text from my phone screen from anywhere in any other app that displays text on the phone screen. How would I go about coding this app?

Comment: How does this differ from the copy/paste functions built into android?

Comment: If you want to code it in Java, why is it tagged with JavaScript and C?

Comment: This is not generally possible, for blindingly obvious privacy and security reasons. You are welcome to explore the accessibility APIs for the limited access you get to this sort of information... once you learn the differences between Java, JavaScript, and C.

Comment: Well it's not just copy and paste  the idea is that you would use this feature to get definitions for a word on your screen without having to exit your app to go search somewhere for definitions

Comment: @ClaudellCarter just to be sure, how is this different from pressing the Home button, then opening an APP to perform the desired effect? Also, most devices allow you to select, mark, then copy the text. You could use this to "gather" the desired text.